# How is $\int_{-T_0/2}^{+T_0/2} \delta(t) \cos(n\omega_0 t)dt=1$ and $\int_{-T_0/2}^{+T_0/2} \delta(t) \sin(n\omega_0 t)=0$?

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing, dirac-delta

In our Circuit Theory class we came across this function:
$$f(t) =
\begin{cases}
\delta(t-nT_0),  & \text{if $t=nT_0$ where $n\in\Bbb{Z}$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

$\delta$ is presumably the dirac-delta function. And we can see that the time period of the function is $T_0$.

One can find the Fourier series for such a periodic function.

$$f(t)=a_0 + a_n \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos(n\omega_0 t) + b_n \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n\omega_0 t)$$ where $\omega_0=\frac{2\pi}{T_0}$.

Now our professor wrote,

$$a_0=\frac{1}{T_0}\int_{-T_0/2}^{+T_0/2} f(t) dt = \frac{1}{T_0}\int_{-T_0/2}^{+T_0/2} \delta(t) dt=\frac{1}{T_0}$$

I think this step is *sort of* justified because $\frac{1}{T_0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta (t) dt \approx \frac{1}{T_0}\int_{-T_0/2}^{+T_0/2} \delta (t) dt$ since $\delta(t)$ blows up only at $t=0$, and in other places it vanishes.

But then my main confusion occurred when he wrote:

$$a_n=\frac{2}{T_0}\int_{-T_0/2}^{+T_0/2} f(t) \cos(n\omega_0 t) dt = \frac{2}{T_0}$$

$$b_n=\frac{2}{T_0}\int_{-T_0/2}^{+T_0/2} f(t) \sin(n\omega_0 t) dt= 0$$

I'm not sure how
$\int_{-T_0/2}^{+T_0/2} \delta(t) \cos(n\omega_0 t)dt=1$ and $\int_{-T_0/2}^{+T_0/2} \delta(t) \sin(n\omega_0 t)=0$.

**Are these standard properties of the delta function? If not, how to find the value of those integrals?**

I couldn't find anything related on the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{-T_0/2}^{+T_0/2} \delta(t) \cos(n\omega_0 t)dt=1$$
$$\int_{-T_0/2}^{+T_0/2} \delta(t) \sin(n\omega_0 t)=0$$

> *Are these standard properties of the delta function? If not, how to find the value of those integrals?*

The answer is yes.

One may [recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Definitions) that

> $$
> \int_{I}\, \delta(t)\,f(t)\,dt=f(0).
> $$

with $0\in I$.

Comment: +1. It would be nice if you could add a proof for $\int_{I}\, \delta(t)\,f(t)\,dt=f(0)$ or just add a link to the proof. It might be in the Wiki page, I'm checking.

Comment: Oh, and I guess measure theory provides a justification for why we can write $\int_{-T_0/2}^{+T_0/2} \delta (t) dt=1$ (?) although the standard property just says $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta (t) dt=1$.